# Making more thatn one card view to be visible in horizontal recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im trying to create horizontally swipeable recyclerview that contains multiple carview items. Following is the way How Im setting the adapter

```
 LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Following is my recyclerview item code layout code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/album_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/overflow"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_margin_top"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dots"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The problem is that only one card is visible at a time but I want more than one card to be visible as in google play . How can I be able to sort this out?

[image: A]

As you can see the layout contains both horizontal recycler view. Then it contains vertical recycler view.  The horizontal recycler view shows only one cardview and show the other views when it is swipes but i want to show multiple views at the same time.

Comment: No need to use Parent linear layout. Parent should be your CardView and then set width/height of CardView to `wrap_content` or any fix dp.

Comment: it shows layout error if i remove linear layout

Comment: you have to set fix width of your cardview

Comment: How to set fixed width of my cardview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

1. Set your parent LinearLayout as well as child views width as `wrap_content`.
2. ImageView with id `overflow` is aligned to right of the parent. Remove that and add `android:layout_alignRight="@id/thumbnail"`
3. Also try a clean & rebuild of your project since sometimes the layout code changes doesn't get reflected while building.

Comment: I removed alignParentRight and i did what you said but the problem is still persisting

Comment: @Learner In your preview page of Android Studio, how this layout is previewing?? Is it fully stretched there also??

Comment: In layout previewing , it is not fully stretched but it is stretched only in device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120241/discussion-between-sjy-and-learner).

Comment: @sJy you should edit your answer or at least comment here that you fixed by cleaning and rebuilding, something I also suggested in chat :/

Answer (score 0):

You should set `layout_width` to `wrap_content` for all ViewGroups (i.e. LinearLayout, CardView and RelativeLayout), it's not enough to set the outer ViewGroups only.

This also applies to all other children, such your ImageView, TextView, etc. In general if a child View has `layout_width` set to `match_parent` and the parent has `wrap_content`, the parent will try to go as big as it can to accommodate this.

Also a point of style, you should name your variables in camel notation, e.g. `horizontal_recycler_view` should be `horizontalRecyclerView`.

Comment: i have tried it and still the same error persists. I have posted the screen shot too . Please read the updated question than you

Comment: All the Views contained in the inner RelativeLayout should also have `layout_width` set to `wrap_parent`, I've updated my answer to show this

Comment: I have changed every thing to wrap_content but still the problem persists. I have even hardcoded the value of width in dp but still the same issue

Comment: Perhaps your images are very big, try setting `scaleType` to `fitCenter` in your ImageView